# storing returned values from functions present in exe file using bat script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to call a function present in saur.exe using bat.
It looks something like this:

```
saur.exe readName
```

When i execute it, it returns a string "Saurabh".

Now that I want to store "saurabh" in a variable called `name`.

So I am doing :

```
set name = saur.exe readName
echo .%name%
```

In this case, it doesnot execute.
It gives blank in front of echo command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some SET command documentation will show that you can only assign strings to environment variables (http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm).

In your example above, you have actually set an environment variable called:

`"name "`

Yet you are echoing the variable:

`"name"`

The best solution I can find is to do something similar to

```
saur.exe readName>tempFile
SET /p variableName=<tempFile
ECHO %variableName%
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Hey Jay, Thanks a lot!! It wrote the file. I am planning to put in c++ program which reads it and prepare a nice GUI type app :)

Comment: A temporary file is way too much overhead. See [eran's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760055/storing-returned-values-from-functions-present-in-exe-file-using-bat-script/7760283#7760283).

Comment: The direct way to do that should be `saur.exe readName | set /p name=`, but this form have an error so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason, doing what you want requires some awkward workarounds. The long way would be to store the output of the command in a file, then read the file into the variable, and finally delete the file. The shorter (and barely readable) way is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('saur.exe readName') do set name=%%a
echo %name%
```

:-(